# Opening a child (non-root) controller from app delegate

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to open a view controller from a deeplink with the following structure:

```
# Regular navigation:
AppDelegate -> A (root) -> B -> C

# Deeplink navigation to a specific controller:
AppDelegate -> B (child of A)
```

I also want to allow a user to use the back navigation to go back to root A (even if I have to create it on clicking back)

Controller A is a mix of complex location listeners and views, so I'd prefer not to instantiate it before opening B.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the location listeners in `viewWillAppear()` in Controller A, then you can instantiate the Controller without setting up the listeners.
Then, you can push `[ControllerA(), ControllerB()]` as your navigation `viewControllers` and build your nav stack.